# Pug isn't outputing my variables on the template side

Tags: php, pug

I'm using Pug in PHP. Right now I am using it with a simple PHP router. I have a server side file `index.php` and a templating file `index.pug`. I am passing the `times` constant to the template.

Here is my code

```
$router->get('/', function() {
    $pug = new Pug();
    $output = $pug->render('views/index.pug', array(
        'title' => times
    ));
    echo $output;
});
```

This is the code I have on my template:

```
p #{visits}
```

When I run the program and render the template, I get this output:

```
<p></p>
```

I checked by logs and I have nothing. For a test, I echoed the output on another page like so...

```
$router->get('/api/visits', function() {
    echo times;
});
```

..and the correct output of `1716` is returned. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: #{visit} expects a key 'visit' in your array, changing the 'title' to 'visit' might work

Comment: Thank you so much! That was very dumb of me.

Comment: you are welcome, also to community :)